# The app build failed to produce artifact folder Angular Azure Static Web App Deployment Issue

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-static-web-app

When i try to build angular app using azure devops and deploy to azure static web app i'm receiving below error

> The app build failed to produce artifact folder: 'dist/harmony-front'. Please
> ensure this property is configured correctly in your deployment
> configuration file.

[image]

I tried by changing `output_location to / , dist, /dist , dist/harmony-front,`

nothing seems to work

here's the yaml code for the deployment section

```
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  inputs:
      app_location: "/"
      api_location: "api"
      output_location: "./dist/harmony-front"
      app_build_command: 'npm run build:prod'
      skip_api_build: true
      verbose: true

  env:
      continueOnError: true
      CUSTOM_BUILD_COMMAND: "npm install --force"
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)
```

What was the mistake i made

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found the issue and will post for future reference. if someone had  the same issue.

issue start when you override build command using `CUSTOM_BUILD_COMMAND` will overwrite the `RUN_BUILD_COMMAND` so based on the [comment of the issue posted on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/1281) instead of `npm install --force` command combined with build like `npm install --force && npm run build`  works like charm

Answer (score 5):

**I have tried to repro the same and got positive results after following the below steps.**

Step 1: Create a simple angular project and build the project on a local machine and inspect the dist folder.

[image]

Step 2: Push the code to Azure Repos.

Step 3: Create azure pipeline as shown below.

```
trigger: none
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
  displayName: 'install angular cli'
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
  displayName: 'npm install'
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'run build'
  displayName: 'npm build'
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      pwd
      ls -l
      ls -l dist/
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  displayName: 'Deploy Azure static webapp'
  inputs:
    app_location: '/'
    output_location: 'dist/my-app'
  env:
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(static-webapp-token)
```

Step 4: Verify the result.

[image]

[image]

If you are still facing that issue, verify the AzureStaticWebApp@0
output location path in angular.json file as below. Both paths must be exact.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i have my angular app named "front-end";

The file angular.json had -> "outputPath" : "dist/front-end"

The .yml had -> output_location: "dist/front-end"

The configuration above gived me the same error.
I have builded the app locally using "ng build" command and I found that the build was generated in the path: "dist/front-end/browser" (With that extra browser file). After I changed the output_location in the .yml file with:

output_location: "dist/front-end/browser"

The issue was fixed.

So, my advice is to try to generate the build locally and check the right path for you.